# Where is the Font "Latin Modern" in Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: 22.04

Hello and sorry for my "English", I am German.
Yesterday i installed Ubuntu 22.04 and delete all not necessary Fonts, like the "Indian-Fonts". But i cant find the Font "Latin Modern".
Does anybody know, where this Font is installed?

Comment: Edited your title to correct the version.

Comment: Look somewhere deep inside `/usr/share/javascript/mathjax/`.

Answer (score 0):

I found it: usr/share/texmf/fonts

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to (or can't) extract the font from a TeX installation, you can also install the font standalone via the `fonts-lmodern` package:

```
sudo apt install fonts-lmodern
```

Source: https://installati.one/install-lmodern-ubuntu-22-04/

Comment: Remember the `universe` repository has to be enabled for this.